# How can I create a matrix from a csv file that displays relations between certain objects?

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, matrix

I have very little experience in programming and I cannot understand how I can turn  a csv file that looks like this:

```
house_1, house_2, distance

John, Mary, 10

Bob, John, 8

Mary, Bob, 7
```

to a matrix that looks like this

```
      John  Mary Bob

 John  0     10    8

 Mary  10     0    7

 Bob   8      7    0
```

using Python

Answer (score 1):

What you have is basically an edge list representing an undirected graph. Two good modules to process this are `pandas` for data management and `networkx` for graph processing:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv') # read csv as pandas dataframe
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'house_1', 'house_2', 'distance') # create networkx graph from dataframe
df_out = nx.to_pandas_adjacency(G, weight='distance') # create adjacency matrix from graph
df_out.to_csv('file_out.csv', index=False) # save to csv
```

Output:

|  | John | Mary | Bob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | 10 | 8 |
| Mary | 10 | 0 | 7 |
| Bob | 8 | 7 | 0 |